# Pound symbol display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, utf-8, character-encoding

I have an mvc solution with a standard view using _Layout page for layout. Layout page has charset=utf-8 set in the header like so:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

For some reason, when I type "£" symbol in the view I get it displayed as "A£", with a dash above "A". At the same time when I put the same symbol in the _Layout page it's displaying fine. I got this resolved by using encoded value

```
&pound;
```

but was wondering why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

It may have happened because of a mismatch between `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` and the encoding of your physical file.

E.g. Your file could be saved as `ISO-8859-1`.

Comment: How can I verify if that's the case?

Comment: Use some text editor, such as notepad2, notepad++ which will let you see the encoding on the file

Comment: The encoding says "UTF-8 w/o BOM" for this file, but no ISO details

Answer (score 0):

I have read that note. I am using Adobe Dreamweaver for all my files and I think it is encoded in 'utf-8'.